# creating events on a facebook fan page with php

Tags: php, facebook

Is it still possible to automatically create facebook events on a Facebook fan page ?

I saw on another topic that it was possible with graph api v1.0 but it is now deprecated...

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you had a previously working solution in mind that is no longer working... Maybe you should include some more details about it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0, it´s not possible anymore:

> Apps can no longer create events with the API.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0